# Jtextfield does not display the text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to pass values from my database java file to my frame java file.BY creating a function like "frame java . get value (name ,phone, date ) " and receiving the value in the frame java file . I tried to  print the passed value in the console it works fine, but when i try to set value to the text field it doesn't display the text in the text filed... I don't what's wrong can any one help me to sort out this issue.

**Here is database java function**

```
public void check_room(String roomno, String date) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "select * from customerinfo where roomno='" + roomno
            + "'and cdate='" + date + "' ";
    System.out.print("search method called \n ");
    System.out.print("\n ");
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hotel", "hotel");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Logger.getLogger(checkout.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
        // null, ex);
    }
    sate = con.createStatement();
    rs = sate.executeQuery(sql);

    int tmp = 0;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print("search found \n ");

            String name = rs.getString("GUEST_NAME");
            String phono = rs.getString("GUEST_PHO");
            String addr = rs.getString("G_ADDR");
            String paid = rs.getString("PAID");
            String total = rs.getString("TOTAL");
            String balance = rs.getString("BALANCE");
            System.out.println(name);

            mainmenu menu = new mainmenu();
            menu.getvalue(name, phono, addr, paid, total, balance);
            tmp++;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Logger.getLogger(checkout.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
        // null, ex);
    }
    if (tmp <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no details found ");
    }
}
```

==========================================================================

**This is  my frame java file**

```
public void getvalue(String name, String phono, String addr, String paid,String total, String balance) {
    nam.setText(name);
    pho.setText(phono);
    // mainmenu();
```

## }

I **edited as u said** but getting error . I have attached my skeleton code 
and the error i get, below

**edited code.**

database file

```
public class OracelThinconnection

{  
  private MainMenu menu;    
   public OracelThinconnection(MainMenu menu)  
  {  
     this.menu=menu;  
..................  
.................   
.............
```

========================================================================
**Error i get**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor OracelThinconnection()
  location: class bookingapp.OracelThinconnection
        at bookingapp.MainMenu.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:1438)
        at bookingapp.MainMenu.access$300(MainMenu.java:33)
        at bookingapp.MainMenu$4.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:379)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: nam.setText(name);

pho.setText(phono);     it should display the value in the text box but it is not displaying the value . anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the code you've not shown, but a guess as to your problem is that you're creating a new instance of your GUI, one not visualized, and trying to send information to it, while the visualized GUI sits unperturbed and un-updated.

The key is that you're creating a ***new*** instance of your mainmenu GUI, one that has no relationship to the one that is displayed. Passing data to this new instance will have no effect on the displayed GUI.

Here:

```
mainmenu menu= new mainmenu();
menu. getvalue (name, phono, addr, paid, total, balance);
```

You're creating a new mainmenu object (the class should be named MainMenu).

A solution, give your Database class a MainMenu field, and pass into this field a valid reference to the main gui, and then call methods on the GUI, but only on the Swing event thread.  For example:

```
public class MyDataBase {
  private MyGui gui;

  // constructor gets passed a reference to the valid displayed GUI
  public MyDataBase(MyGui gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  public void someDataBaseMethod() {
    // get database information

    // now you can call methods on the actual displayed GUI
    // but on the Swing event thread only. The SwingUtilities.invokeLater
    // with the Runnable is required to be sure that you don't mess up
    // Swing's threading model.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // this method below is being called on the 
        // displayed MyGui instance.
        gui.updateGuiWithInformation(....); // some update method of the GUI
      }
    });
  }
```

The key -- **don't** create a new GUI instance inside of the database code.

---

OK, you've changed your code and now have a constructor that looks like so:

```
public OracelThinconnection(MainMenu menu)  {
   // ....
}
```

Now you need to look at the line that the error is pointing to, `MainMenu.java:1438`, line 1438 (1438????) of the MainMenu class. On that line you likely call the OracelThinconnection constructor but are not passing the current MainMenu instance into it. The new constructor will accept a MainMenu reference, but when you call the constructor, you now have to remember to ***pass that reference in*** to the constructor.

Specifically, change it from

```
// not sure what you name the variable below
// but I just gave it thinConnection for now.
OracelThinconnection thinConnection = new OracelThinconnection();
```

to this:

```
OracelThinconnection thinConnection = new OracelThinconnection(this);
```

or if this doesn't work, then

```
OracelThinconnection thinConnection = new OracelThinconnection(MainMenu.this);
```

As an addendum, your code obviously has more than 1400 lines which tells you that you've got some huge God class that tries to do any thing and everything. I strongly urge you to refactor this code, to make smaller classes, each with their own sphere of responsibilities, else you will not be able to debug or enhance this program.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me , its not a problem i guess because i kept the java file name so .And also i tried changing to   MainMenu still have the same issue ...

Comment: @kabilesh: what do you mean by `" its not a problem i guess because i kept the java fail name so .And also i tried changing to MainMenu still have the same issue."` -- are you sure that you understand my recommendations fully? I suspect that what I've posted does summarize the problem. The key is that you're creating a ***new*** instance of your mainmenu GUI, one that has no relationship to the one that is displayed. Passing data to this new instance will have no effect on the displayed GUI.

Comment: I am new to java , can you just brief me wat i am wrong actually .

Comment: @kabilesh: I thought that I did that. Please specify just what you're not understanding. Please don't make me re-write everything over again without telling me how you're confused. I'm posting pseudo code showing general concepts. I'm sure that you've got the smarts to extend this information to the specifics of your code. Please give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i understood what your saying friend . sure  thanks i will try it.

Comment: Thank you  for your patience and helping me . I understood and edited my code as u said.I am getting error . my code

public class OracelThinconnection

{
 private MainMenu menu;

  public OracelThinconnection(MainMenu menu)
  {
      this.menu=menu;
.............
===========================================
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor OracelThinconnection()

Comment: @kabilesh: please edit your original question and post the new information at the bottom. Please don't delete the code and question already present, but rather add the new information at the bottom. Then please send me a comment to let me know you've done this.

Comment: Full Of Eles  i added information at the bottom. please do check .

Comment: @kabilesh: thanks for the information. Please see edit to question.

Comment: i cont see wat you edited in that so could you please highlight the corrected code ...

Comment: @kabilesh:what do you mean you can't see what I edit? All the new information in my post is at the bottom, starting on the line that begins `"OK, you've changed your code ...."`. Please re-read the answer from there.

Comment: thank you my friend but i never find those lines in my posted question , it shows rev: you are edited it, can u just check fr me once again.